# prevent submit until input change

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

I have this little code to post via ajax:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var myName = $('#name').val();
    var myContent = $('#content').val();

    // ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/ajax.process.php',
        data: {
            post_name: myName,
            post_content: myContent
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        alert(OK);
        }
    }); // end ajax
});
```

How I can prevent or disable the .click until my inputs are changed, I mean until user make some modification?

Comment: Do you want to allow the AJAX request if **any** `input` has changed, or **all** your `input` fields have changed?

Comment: Any inputs of course! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace submit with type="button" and use that ajax on users input change, like:

```
//make input type="submit" to
<input type="button".... />

$("yourInputId").blur(function() {
  $.ajax({}); // use ur ajax here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best, and most visible, solution is to set the `disabled` attribute on your submit button initially (`input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" disabled>`), and then remove that attribute (`$('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');`) when the user changes the value of whatever inputs you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a flag on top `var canSubmit = false;` and change it to true on the text field's `$.change()` event.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the submit button and then can show them once teh change method for your inputs is called like

```
$("input").change(function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").show()
});
```